# Using a sequence as data point for multiple features

Tags: machine-learning

I was wondering if it was possible to have a sequence as input to a model ?

For example, let's say I have some hourly data for multiple days. This includes both a response variable and x predictor variables. Each with 24 data points for each day. Then I need to not forecast, but predict an entire sequence/curve based on sequenced input data from the predictor variables.

So for example my data set could look something like this:

```
df =
                    response    var1    var2    var3
date
2021/06/04 00:00:00     10      116      221      64
2021/06/04 01:00:00     11      155      201      74
2021/06/04 02:00:00     14      122      331      84
2021/06/04 03:00:00     12      136      204      24
2021/06/04 04:00:00     17      148      101      34
2021/06/04 05:00:00     18      167      505      54
2021/06/04 06:00:00     20      126      406      24
2021/06/04 07:00:00     21      153      302      14
2021/06/04 08:00:00     18      167      505      54
2021/06/04 09:00:00     20      126      406      24
2021/06/04 10:00:00     21      153      302      14
```

And then obviously all hours for a day, and multiple days.

Is this possible in any way, i.e. using entire sequences as input to predict a sequence of values, and  or...?

Comment: What you asked can be done, but its a complete topic on its own. What I can suggest right now, for an easy practical explanation, read the time-series analysis chapter from the following book that is based upon R: https://rc2e.com/timeseriesanalysis

Comment: But that chapter looks to describe time series in general, and lastly to do some forecasting using ARIMA. It's not forecasting I am looking for. That would mean it would try to predict how the time series evolves days,/weeks/months ahead. In my case, the data from tomorrow might not look at all like the day before that. It might look like data from 6 months ago or so. Hence it's not really forecasting, as much as prediction with sequences of data as input.

Comment: @DenverDang so you are saying there is no time dependence? In such a case, why would you care about the data being a series?

Comment: There is a time dependence for the particular days. Some days might look similar, but not necessarily days close to each other. Hence, I'm not looking for a forecast. I don't need to predict the following weeks based on no inputs and just historical data. 

For each day I will have 24 data points for each predictor. I then want to predict the structure/values of a new response sequence when new predictor sequences are used as input.

Comment: In general, I could just compare a bunch of curves/sequences for each predictor, get some kind of score, minimize the score, and then use the response sequence for the lowest scored days to average some kind of curve. But I was thinking there had to be a better solution than that.

I could also just create a model for each specific hour. I am just afraid that some information from the rest of the hours will be lost if done that way.